# what should i write in place of ***** or how can i access this local varaible in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

what should I write in place of ***** or how can I access this local variable in RSpec?

**User model**

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User<ApplicationRecord
  def update
    ......
    my_variable=Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({....}) // real time response
    ......
  end
end
```

**User spec**

```
#spec/models/user_spec.rb
RSpec.describe User, type::model do
  pp ****my_variable
end
```

Comment: Well, you should not be able to do that. You have to test what the method does or returns, not the state of some local variables.

Answer (score 0):

We should mock the API calls to external services in the test cases. So, in your case, you can mock the `Stripe::PaymentIntent.create` API call and test the return value of your method based on the other conditions.